# Error when enter "8" in Japanese keyboard

Tags: html, laravel

I have a crazy problem when I code an admin page. When i enter the "8" to this dialog, its how me like this picture. Every button else is ok.

[image]

Here my code:

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h4>{{'TITLE'|translate}}</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="addPoint()" id="add-point-form">
      <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">{{'AMOUNT'|translate}}</label>
        <div class="controls">
          <input type="number" ng-model="input.amount" required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="close()">{{'CANCEL'|translate}}</button>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" form="add-point-form">{{'CONFIRM'|translate}}</button>
</div>
```

I don't know why 8?

Comment: Try adding <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> to your <head> section

Comment: Could you tell me why? Pugazh.Thank You.

Comment: The charset attribute specifies the character encoding for the HTML document. Did this helped ?

Comment: No! It did not helped.